# Restrict URL tampering in Spring Framework 3.1

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am building an application using Spring Framework 3.1

I am having my controllers mapped with url containing path variables that stands for some id.
But I don't want the user to tamper with the url and change the path variable value manually.
I want to restrict them from doing so.

I have already tried using the ShallowEtagHeaderFilter. But its not working the way it suppose to.
I don't know whether I missed any configuration for the filter or its not working at all.

here is my web.xml where I have configured the dispatcher servlet and filter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>eTagFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.abc.config.EtagFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>eTagFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

</web-app>
```

Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand how ShallowEtagHeaderFilter fits into this picture, I think you misunderstood its functionality. It's supposed to reduce network traffic by taking pages from the browser cache. That's a totally different scenario from yours.

Basically: if you don't want users to tamper with URLs, you will need to have a way to verify that the URL was created by your application, usually a checksum parameter of some sort with an algorithm that's not easy to guess.

e.g. `/site/12/user/12345/aB` where `aB` is calculated based on `/site/12/user/12345`. Now if the user changes the URL to `/site/13/user/12345/aB` the checksum is wrong and you can send a 404 or a 400 or whatever error you want to send.

I'd probably implement the checksum check as a Filter and write a utility method that creates URLs with checksum based on plain URLs (possibly you'll need a JSP tag as well)

Comment: Hi Patrick.. Thanks for the quick answer.

I totally agree with you that I misunderstood the functionality. And also your suggestion is perfectly what I need.

Can you please give some more bried idea about this by providing an example to do this?

Comment: @JapanTrivedi checksum algorithms are not my specialty, but there's an entire section about them on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Checksum_algorithms . Perhaps you can start there and when you have more specific questions, come back for more help.

Comment: one more thing I would like to ask you about.
In your answer you have mentioned about the JSP tag.
Which JSP tag are you talking about?
Please elaborate that. Thanks. :)

Comment: Assuming that you want to create links inside a JSP, you will have to write a tag like `<c:link>` that creates URLs with your checksum algorithm

Comment: Ya... I got it.
I am also planning to check out the urlrewrite api.
I will use it to append the calculated checksum value to it and then it will be displayed to the user.

Any inputs about this api from you?

Comment: Hi... Need one more help.
I have implemented checksum in one filter.
But how to append this checksum for each and every request from the filter?
I'm stuck. Please help.

Comment: @JapanTrivedi ask a new question, linking to this one

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I have found one great API for all the Security I want to apply on my web application. Its HDIV. I don't know if you know about it or not. FYI only, I'm now using this to restrict the URL access and other security. :)

Comment: @JapanTrivedi yeah, that looks like it does the job nicely